# End/exit a glue job programmatically

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue, exit, aws-glue-spark

I am using Glue bookmarking to process data. My job is scheduled every day, but can also be launch "manually". Since I use bookmarks, sometimes the Glue job can start without having new data to process, the read dataframe is then empty. In this case, I want to end my job properly because it has nothing to do.
I tried:

```
if df.rdd.isEmpty():
    job.commit()
    sys.exit(0)
```

However, my job terminate in error with `SystemExit: 0`.

How to end the job with success?

Comment: My question is a fork of the not working answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67028388/how-to-stop-exit-a-aws-glue-job-pyspark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some test, I discovered from [@Glyph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76374/3710514) that :

> `os._exit()` terminates immediately at the C level and does not perform any of the normal tear-downs of the interpreter.

Which is exactly what I was looking for. The final solution is:

```
import os

if df.rdd.isEmpty():
    job.commit()
    os._exit()
```

Comment: In my case `os._exit()` was failling with error **_TypeError: _exit() missing required argument 'status' (pos 1)_** . I had to provide one of the status of exit. For success you can provide 0 as a status   `os._exit(0)`   . For other status this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit) can be referred.

Answer (score 7):

Just using `os._exit()` doesn't work in Glue Version 3.0

To exit a job gracefully after some conditions have been met, use:

```
import os
import sys
.
. # Your Glue Job Code
.
logger.info("Existing job gracefully...") # Or a simple print; print("...")
job.commit() # Only necessary if you are loading data from s3 and you have job bookmarks enabled.
os._exit(0) # Using a 0 status code throws no exception so your job completes with a succeeded status.
```

But, if you want to exit with an error use:

```
sys.exit("Error Message...") # this will exit with an error message that will be displayed on the Glue UI -- Run Details --, and the job would have a status of failed.
```